# difference (or relationship ?) between power spectral density, power density function and periodogram

Tags: power-spectral-density

What exactly is the difference or relationship between power spectral density and power density function? I thought they referred to the same thing but one article I need says to calculate both of them so now I don't know if they are different. A layman's explanation or explanation in terms of physical meaning would be better. Also what is it's relation ship with periodogram? If X(f) is the DFT of x(t), then is $|X(f)|^2$  same as periodogram?

Comment: 17% is still not exactly stellar - did you really not want to show any appreciation for any of the answers to all your previous questions ?